# printing pandas Index in full

Tags: python, pandas

In order to print pandas `DataFrame` or `Series` in full, we can use `pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)`. But this doesn't seem to work on the `Index` datatype:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None) # just in case
d = {i: ['a'] for i in range(1000)}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
print(df.columns)
```

will print

```
Int64Index([  0,   1,   2,   3,   4,   5,   6,   7,   8,   9,
        ...
        990, 991, 992, 993, 994, 995, 996, 997, 998, 999],
       dtype='int64', length=1000)
```

Is there a way to make the index print in full?

In general, is there a way to tell pandas to never abbreviate any output?

(python 3.5, pandas 0.17.1, but it shouldn't matter.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's the option `max_seq_items` that is used for this:

```
In [21]: pd.options.display.max_seq_items
Out[21]: 100

In [22]: pd.options.display.max_seq_items = 4

In [23]: pd.Index(range(1000))
Out[23]:
Int64Index([  0,   1,
            ...
            998, 999], dtype='int64', length=1000)
```

And setting it to `None` will display the full index.

Comment: Same as `pd.set_option('display.max_seq_items', None)`?

Comment: Indeed, that is the same

Answer (score 1):

If the purpose of printing is to see the data from the console, You could turn it into a python list.

```
print(list(df.columns))
```

This should show the data in full without any abbreviate. However this may not be the solution to tell pandas to not abbreviate an output.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35010081)

Comment: Nice answer, I don't know why it did not get upvoted

Answer (score 0):

Here is a concise way to get what you want:

```
for i in df.columns:
    print(i,end=", ")
```

the value of the `end` parameter can be anything you like, including the default `\n`.